# insert 1 million rows into MS sql server-2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am writing a huge data into tables in sql server 2008 with visual studio 2010. But the common insert into procedure is too slow and data missing. I am newer to the sql server, so how can i insert 1 million rows to an exisiting talbe in SQL Server 2008(Local database). Thanks.

```
      int len = arrayNo.GetSize();
        for (int z=0 ;z<len;z++)
        {
            tmp1= arrayNo.GetAt(z);
            tmp2= arrayID.GetAt(z);
            tmp3= arrayDuration.GetAt(z);
            tmp4= arrayState.GetAt(z);
            CString str;
            str.Format(_T("('%s','%s','%s',%s)"),tmp1, tmp2,tmp3,tmp4);
            strQuery = _T("insert into  [Zhaoyangqing].[dbo].[GameStateOutput]  values ")+str; 
            theApp.ADOExecute(theApp.m_pADOSet, strQuery);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from? You look like you're inserting with a loop, which is going to be very slow. 1 million rows, honestly, on DBMS terms is really not a "huge" table, it's when you start getting to the 100's of millions, or billionsz that it really starting to get "huge". Any good RDBMS, with a well designed database, can handle the insertion of 1M rows in a few seconds.

Comment: The data is generated by myself in StingArray stuct. Thanks. The destination talble is very simple, the loop is not good indeed, so how i can handle this problem?

Comment: So why not generate the data in T-SQL if you're generating it in C++ instead? You're using SQL, use a set based method here; you'll have vastly better performance.

Comment: I read the source data from source table, after the processing (some calcuation) ,there are new item gernerated, then i wanna store this new information. can U provide some example? thanks lot.

Comment: *"I read the source data from source table,"* vs *"The data is generated by myself in StingArray stuct."* Those statements completely conflict. Are *you* generating the data, or are you getting it from a SQL Table? HOw can I provide an example of a process I have no idea about. SAmple data, expected results, ***all*** the **relevant** code to create an [mre] are needed here. Otherwise, best I can suggest is look up `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM` syntax.

Comment: sorry to confuse you, my point is we read the raw data form table in database, we process those data and generated the new information line by line. Now i want to insert those new information to the new table. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: insert into select from is not fit for me, cause those new information is not in the exist table.

Comment: As I said *"SAmple data, expected results, all the relevant code to create an minimal reproducible example are needed here."* Without that, we can't help you; you haven't explained your goal. If you want a fast solution, use a set based solution in the RDBMS, don't use C++ and an iterative task. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest improvement is to wrap the inserts into a transaction.  That way SQL Server doesn't have to flush the log file after every row.

Perhaps something like:

```
    strQuery = _T("begin transaction"); 
    theApp.ADOExecute(theApp.m_pADOSet, strQuery);

    int len = arrayNo.GetSize();
    for (int z=0 ;z<len;z++)
    {
        tmp1= arrayNo.GetAt(z);
        tmp2= arrayID.GetAt(z);
        tmp3= arrayDuration.GetAt(z);
        tmp4= arrayState.GetAt(z);
        CString str;
        str.Format(_T("('%s','%s','%s',%s)"),tmp1, tmp2,tmp3,tmp4);
        strQuery = _T("insert into  [Zhaoyangqing].[dbo].[GameStateOutput]  values ")+str; 
        theApp.ADOExecute(theApp.m_pADOSet, strQuery);
    }

    strQuery = _T("commit transaction"); 
    theApp.ADOExecute(theApp.m_pADOSet, strQuery);
```

> sql server 2008 with visual studio 2010

And why are you using such old and unsupported software?  There are faster ways to load data into SQL Server, but it's going to be difficult with the what you're using.